# What are the common use cases for which Spark MMLIB should not be used

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am interested in knowing, use cases in which Spark MMLIB shouldn't be used.

Comment: Plain and simple - when you dont want to use machine-learning - Like filtering data (just create alerts from events), aggregation (see how many ERRORs are generated by logger for last 30minutes), store stream data somewhere for historic searching.... Basically process data without any other goals that need machine-learning.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you should reconsider you choice when:

- You need an exact solution or well defined error. Spark MLlib typically use heuristics additionally adjusted for Spark architecture. Some give very good results in general, other may require complex tuning.
- You have thin data / low number of dimensions (up to few thousands) or data fits in a memory of a single node (easily 256GB - 512GB as today). Optimized machine learning / linear algebra library usually performs much better than Spark with this conditions.
- You want to collect detailed diagnostic information during training process. MLlib algorithms are usually black boxes.
- Model is to be used outside Spark. Export options are fairly limited.